# Zsh wants to autocorrect a command, with an _ before it

Tags: zsh

I just started using Zsh lately for some of the integrated support in the shell prompt for my Git status etc.

When I type in:

```
 ruby -v
```

to confirm the version of ruby I'm running, Zsh asks if I want to change the command to _ruby. Well after saying no at the prompt and the command completing as expected I continue to get the question at the prompt after confirming my command is correct.

I'm assuming there is a completion file or something of the sort.

Thanks

**Update:**

The shell is no longer trying to complete _ruby, it stopped responding after closing the shell a few times some how.

I tried to clean the file up several times but there is a "opts" variable that is 50 or more lines long and the lines are all ran together, some lines more than 150 characters. Maybe I could email an attachment to you if you still want to see it.
I sincerely apologize for the messy post.

Comment: I don't see that behavior. What version of zsh? What's in your `~/.zshrc`? Does it do that if you try to run a simple ruby CLI script (eg. `ruby -e 'print "hi\n"'`)? Post your `/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Unix/_ruby` file and we can check it against a known-good version.

Comment: What about the other questions I asked? I don't understand - are you still having the problem? If you want someone to be sure and see your followups, address a comment to @username saying something like "see the edited question" if the information itself is too long to fit in the comment. That lights up the user's notification icon (the little envelope at the top of the page).

Comment: @Dennis Williamson It turns out the answer by Gilles is correct. I believe it corrected itself after restarting the shell or logging out. I wasn't certain if I logged out or not. 

"I don't understand - are you still having the problem?"

 As I said in the post, the ruby command would run after I opted out of letting zsh change it to _ruby. So yes everything is working. Thanks for the heads up

Comment: Did you have a file or folder name `_ruby` in the working directory? I have a git repository with a folder named `stats` and every time I type `git status`, zsh want to “correct” it to `git stats`. For me it’s oh-my-zsh that activated the `correct` option, I’m starting to hate the thing.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

This is command autocorrection, activated by the `correct` option. It has nothing to do with completion. You're seeing `_ruby` because zsh thinks there is no `ruby` command and it offers `_ruby` as the nearest existing match.

If you've just installed `ruby`, it's possible that `zsh` has memorized the list of available command earlier, and it won't always try to see if the command has appeared in between. In that case, run `hash -rf`. Future zsh sessions won't have this problem since the `ruby` command already existed when they started.

Sometimes, when you change your `PATH`, zsh forgets some hashed commands. The option `hash_listall` helps against this. As above, if you can force zsh to refresh its command cache with `hash -rf`.

Comment: that is definitely what was going on. It seems it corrected itself after a bit. It may have restarting the shell or from logging out. I can't recall if I logged out so I don't want to say it corrected only by restarting the shell. The only thing that puzzles me is how the command completes successfully when opting out to let zsh change it. I guess as you were saying it had something to do with the shell not "knowing" about the ruby command being available at the time.
Thanks for the answer

Comment: On a side note, I'm using zsh 4.3.12 (i386-apple-darwin11.0.0) and `hash_listall` is not found. However `hash -rf` solved my issue with zsh constantly wanting to autocorrect something I installed recently.

Comment: I'm having this issue with my git-alias `git lg` which zsh believes should be `git log`. There's a reason I call it `lg` and that is because it is similar to `log`, because its function is similar! How to fix this problem? I really don't want to develop a habit of pressing enter twice.

Answer (score 23):

You could make an alias:

`alias ruby='nocorrect ruby'`

It's what I did when zsh kept asking me if I meant `.meteor` when I typed `meteor` because auto-correct is still useful from time to time.

Comment: Easily find this the most useful

Answer (score 15):

I find the autocorrect feature can get annoying at times. So I do in my ~/.zshrc,

```
DISABLE_CORRECTION="true"
```

Comment: Better yet, create aliases to turn auto-correction on and off, because *most* of the time, you want it, particularly if you're using a lot of plugins.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem even when the command is not installed.

I can solve it using the `CORRECT_IGNORE` variable in my `.zshrc`

```
# OPTs to enable
setopt HASH_LIST_ALL
setopt CORRECT
# Zsh variable to determine what to ignore,
# in this case everything starting with _ or . 
CORRECT_IGNORE="[_|.]*"
```

I hope it helps to you or anyone with this issue

Comment: thanks, this is the solution to the actual underlying problem :)

Answer (score 3):

Just a note, on my zsh (version 5.7.1 on macOS), the DISABLE_CORRECTION didn't work.

I saw in my .zshrc file the following two lines, which I then commented out

```
setopt CORRECT
setopt CORRECT_ALL
```

That did it for me.

Answer (score 2):

Sometime ago after an update, I got ***command auto-correction*** enabled which I don't want. If the same happened to you and you want to revert it, in the **~/.zshrc** file you'll have make it:
`# Uncomment the following line to enable command auto-correction.`
`ENABLE_CORRECTION="false"`

or comment it as per bellow:
`# Uncomment the following line to enable command auto-correction.`
`# ENABLE_CORRECTION="true"`