# zsh overzealously trying to correct feature to features

Tags: git, zsh, git-flow

I am using git and zsh. Our boss is using git-flow. Zsh keeps asking me if I mistyped 'features' as 'feature'. A colleague stopped using zsh out of fury for this very reason, we must fix this problem to bring him back into the light of zsh!

```
rainbow@pony:~/ruby-project-9000 (*) (!)
> git push origin feature/power_level
zsh: correct 'feature/power_level' to 'features/power_level' [nyae]? n
```

---

### Update: *disable autocorrect completely*

It **was** just *correct_all*, as in the accepted answer, but the syntax for disabling zsh autocorrect varies over its updates. The following should be a catch all:

```
source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
DISABLE_CORRECTION="true"
unsetopt correct
unsetopt correct_all
```

DISABLE_CORRECTION="true" - is currently what works for me, [learned from here](http://yountlabs.com/blog/2010/11/06/disable-autocorrect-in-zsh/)

---

### Update: *disabling autocorrect for specific commands*

To specifically disable it autocorrecting commands, but unfortunately not "features" as it is a directory (thanks answers below!), see [this solution for exempting commands](https://gist.github.com/vitormil/4364864)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437454/zsh-questioning-correct-command-how-to-stop

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turn off feature completely:

```
unsetopt correct_all
```

Comment: Had a look at Nevik's comment's post, there was no mention of how to add "feature" manually to the list of commands zsh knows? That would be super good 0_0 Other than this 'features' nonsense, zsh's correction has been useful.

Comment: @RainbowPony You can’t add this. The only thing zsh corrects here is file/directory names. If you have such kind of autocorrection it means that you have directory `features` in the current directory, thats all.

Comment: @RainbowPony I constantly run in this issue if I launch things from `$HOME`: it is common that program called `foo` has configuration directory named `.foo` in `$HOME`. Then what happens if you try to do `sudo foo`? Correct, zsh asks whether you meant `sudo .foo`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem (as @ZyX hints at) is that you have a similar name for your git flow feature branch root and your Cucumber test folder which is called features. Zsh thinks they're close enough that it's a typo.

You have two options - use a different name for you feature branches (when you `git flow init`) use a different folder name for your Cucumber tests.

I went with the latter because 'git flow init' is relatively automatic for most people, Cucumber test location is generally used by code, not humans and when people can't find it they will fail safe (i.e. they would have to look for the tests)

Answer (score 0):

with the latest version, `unsetopt correct_all` doesn't work. It is instead `unsetopt correct`. A better solution would be to have `DISABLE_CORRECTION="true"` in the ~/.zshrc file